Order by extreme performance impact
I have a complex query in SQL Server which take 70 seconds to complete with 3,000,000 records.
When I remove the two ORDER BY clauses, it just takes 0.5 seconds to complete.
SELECT TOP 100
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY format([DetectionDateTime],'yyyy/MM/dd') DESC , [DetectionTime] DESC) AS RowId,
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        dbo.tblValidDetections.Id,
        dbo.tblCameras.CameraName, 
        TRY_CAST((TRY_CAST(dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionDate as varchar)
            +  ' '
            + TRY_CAST(dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionTime As varchar)) as datetime)
            as DetectionDateTime, 
        format(dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa') AS DetectionDatePersian,
        dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionTime,
        TRY_CAST(dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionTime as varchar) AS DetectionTimeAsString,
        dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakCitySection,
        dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakRightSection,
        dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakAlphabetSection, 
        dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakLeftSection, 
        dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakCitySection + N' - ' + 
            dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakRightSection + N' ' + 
            dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakAlphabetSection + N' ' + 
            dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakLeftSection
            AS Pelak, 
        CASE
            WHEN dbo.tblValidDetections.Direction = 1 THEN N'In'
            WHEN dbo.tblValidDetections.Direction = 0 THEN N'Out'
            ELSE N'N/A'
            END AS CarDirection,
        dbo.__tbl_base_PelakTypesFarsi.pelakType, 
        dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList.ProvinceName, 
        dbo.__tbl_base_CityList.CityName
    FROM dbo.tblValidDetections 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblCameras 
        ON dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionCameraId = dbo.tblCameras.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_PelakTypesFarsi 
        ON dbo.tblValidDetections.PelakTypeId = dbo.__tbl_base_PelakTypesFarsi.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_CityList 
        ON dbo.tblValidDetections.CityId = dbo.__tbl_base_CityList.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList 
        ON dbo.tblValidDetections.ProvinceId = dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList.Id
        AND dbo.__tbl_base_CityList.ProvinceId = dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList.Id
) As DetectionView  
ORDER BY
    format([DetectionDateTime],'yyyy/MM/dd') DESC,
    [DetectionTime] DESC

I've converted DetectionDate to the fa culture to get the Persian Calendar date, which I don't think has to do with performance here.

As @T-N great suggestion in a comment on his answer to use a single DateTime2 column , I redesigned my table as below

SELECT TOP 1000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(date, VD.DetectionDateTime) DESC , CONVERT(time, VD.DetectionDateTime) DESC) AS RowId,
    VD.Id,
    C.CameraName, 
    VD.DetectionDateTime, 
    CONVERT(date, VD.DetectionDateTime) as DetectionDate,
    CONVERT(time, VD.DetectionDateTime) as DetectionTime,
    format(VD.DetectionDateTime, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa') AS DetectionDatePersian,
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(time, VD.DetectionDateTime)) As DetectionTimeAsString,
    VD.PelakCitySection,
    VD.PelakRightSection,
    VD.PelakAlphabetSection, 
    VD.PelakLeftSection, 
    VD.PelakCitySection + N' - ' + 
        VD.PelakRightSection + N' ' + 
        VD.PelakAlphabetSection + N' ' + 
        VD.PelakLeftSection
        AS Pelak, 
    CASE
        WHEN VD.Direction = 1 THEN N'In'
        WHEN VD.Direction = 0 THEN N'Out'
        ELSE N'N/A'
        END AS CarDirection,
    PTF.pelakType, 
    PL.ProvinceName, 
    CL.CityName,
    VD.CarColor,
    VD.CarType,
    VD.CarSpeed
FROM dbo.tblValidDetections VD
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCameras C
    ON VD.DetectionCameraId = C.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_PelakTypesFarsi PTF
    ON VD.PelakTypeId = PTF.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_CityList CL
    ON VD.CityId = CL.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList PL
    ON VD.ProvinceId = PL.Id
    AND CL.ProvinceId = PL.Id

WHERE  DetectionDateTime >='2024-04-12 00:00:00' AND DetectionDateTime <= '2024-04-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, VD.DetectionDateTime) DESC , CONVERT(time, VD.DetectionDateTime) DESC

It's working and the performance is not bad ( about 2 seconds to get the 1K records via 3M total records)
But I think it can be more efficient because I've used CONVERTs repeatedly.

format([DetectionDateTime],'yyyy/MM/dd') DESC in ORDER BY is unnecessary and prevents the use of the index. Use ORDER BY DetectionDateTime DESC. And you must have index on DetectionDateTime.   As DetectionView seems as typo.

Your formatting and manipulations of the datetime are the issue. Please provide table definitions and sample data for us to be able to provide alternatives for you. Please read [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

without order by, it might not need to materialize whole result table but just 100 rows, which might explain the performance. Also, in general, avoid FORMAT function, it's slow. format([DetectionDateTime],'yyyy/MM/dd') is same as CAST(DetectionDateTime as date) but without the perf. hit. Also, avoid three-part column names, it's absolutely unreadable. You should use short table aliases instead.

As an FYI, 3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the FROM and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

In fact, use ORDER BY DetectionDate DESC, DetectionTime in both the final ORDER BY and the ROW_NUMBER. Please show tables and index definitions, and share the query plan via PasteThePlan

@siggemannen I think it's NOT possibe to convert DateTime to the Persian Calendar with CAST.

I'm not asking you to do that for format(dbo.tblValidDetections.DetectionDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa') calls but for format([DetectionDateTime],'yyyy/MM/dd') calls

As others have stated, the main problem is that you have used calculated values in your ORDER BY clauses - both for the main query and in the ROW_NUMBER() calculation. That eliminates any possibility that SQL server can use a index to efficiently limit the query results to the most recent 100 rows.
So, the first thing to do is to replace those ORDER BY expressions with direct column references in both places - ORDER BY DetectionDate DESC, DetectionTime DESC. You also need to ensure that you have an appropriate index on tblValidDetections(DetectionDate, DetectionTime), or some index that starts with those two columns.
As far as I can tell, the subselect is no longer needed, so it can be eliminated.
Lastly, to reduce clutter and improve readability, defining table aliases and using them to qualify all column references is good practice.
The result would be something like:
SELECT TOP 100
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VD.DetectionDate DESC, VD.DetectionTime DESC) AS RowId,
    VD.Id,
    C.CameraName, 
    TRY_CAST((TRY_CAST(VD.DetectionDate as varchar)
        +  ' '
        + TRY_CAST(VD.DetectionTime As varchar)) as datetime)
        as DetectionDateTime, 
    format(VD.DetectionDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa') AS DetectionDatePersian,
    VD.DetectionTime,
    TRY_CAST(VD.DetectionTime as varchar) AS DetectionTimeAsString,
    VD.PelakCitySection,
    VD.PelakRightSection,
    VD.PelakAlphabetSection, 
    VD.PelakLeftSection, 
    VD.PelakCitySection + N' - ' + 
        VD.PelakRightSection + N' ' + 
        VD.PelakAlphabetSection + N' ' + 
        VD.PelakLeftSection
        AS Pelak, 
    CASE
        WHEN VD.Direction = 1 THEN N'In'
        WHEN VD.Direction = 0 THEN N'Out'
        ELSE N'N/A'
        END AS CarDirection,
    PTF.pelakType, 
    PL.ProvinceName, 
    CL.CityName
FROM dbo.tblValidDetections VD
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCameras C
    ON VD.DetectionCameraId = C.Id 
INNER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_PelakTypesFarsi PTF
    ON VD.PelakTypeId = PTF.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_CityList CL
    ON VD.CityId = CL.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.__tbl_base_ProvinceList PL
    ON VD.ProvinceId = PL.Id
    AND CL.ProvinceId = PL.Id
ORDER BY VD.DetectionDate DESC, VD.DetectionTime DESC

If you original DetectionView subquery was actually a VIEW (that you embedded in the query just for this question), you will need to modify that view to expose the original DetectionDate and DetectionTime columns. This would then allow the outer query to reference them as needed. Your final select list would need to explicitly pick the desired columns instead of using *, if you with to exclude those columns from the final results.

Great ! with more than 3M records in total , it just took 1 second to get the 100K records.
But I can not access the 'DetectionDateTime' field at the end of the script ! ( to apply WHERE and filter out the result based on the 'DetectionDateTime'.
I have to mention this script is dynamic ( because of various order by options ) , so there is no a pre-defined View in SQL Server.

You did not include a WHERE condition in your original post, so that was not addressed. If the condition applies to the date part only, you can apply it to just the VD.DetectionDate column. If the limit values are not DATE or DATETIME types, convert them to match the column type. Do not format the column to match the limit values, or the performance will suffer. ...

... If your WHERE condition involves date and time, the best approach may be to (1) add a computed, persisted DetectionDateTime column to your tblValidDetections table, using something like ALTER TABLE tblValidDetections ADD DetectionDateTime AS DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DetectionDate), CONVERT(DATETIME2, DetectionTime)) PERSISTED. (2) define an index on that new column (very important). (3) Reference that new computed column in both your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

Yes, the above "date + time" calculation is odd and awkward looking, but that appears to be the best efficient way to add DATE and TIME types in SQL Server. Conversions to and from character types to accomplish this are best avoided.  See this db<>fiddle that shows the execution plan using some generated scattered date/time data.

I really appreciate for your time and answers , What's the difference between filling the tblValidDetections.DetectionDateTime from my C# code and using a PERSISTED field ?
The reason I design this way is to NOT store data physically in database when I can calculate them !

If I were designing the data, I would use a single DATETIME or DATETIME2 column to hold combined date and time. That would allow easy filtering or ordering by the combined column. When needed, it is easy enough to extract the date and time components using CAST() or CONVERT(). If you reference them often, you could add them back as computed columns.

I redesigned my table on original post as you suggested to use a single DatetTime2
